# How to open a Popup in a Surface Hub App in UWP when the application is in the background?

Tags: uwp, surface-hub

I am developing a surface hub application wherein I am running a timer when the application is going into the background. 
At a specific point of time , I need to show up a popup in the center of the screen irrespective the application state - Minimized or active.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you register an [in-process background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-an-inproc-background-task) with a time trigger, every time span the background task triggered it will invoke the [`OnBackgroundActivated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Application#Windows_UI_Xaml_Application_OnBackgroundActivated_Windows_ApplicationModel_Activation_BackgroundActivatedEventArgs_) event. So you may define the popup code inside this event. No matter your app is minimized or active the in-process background task will be triggered. For example:

Register:

```
public MainPage()
{
   this.InitializeComponent();
   var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
   builder.Name = "My Background Trigger";
   builder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15, true));      
   BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();
}
```

Override `OnBackgroundActivated` event and show a simple popup.

```
protected async override void OnBackgroundActivated(BackgroundActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnBackgroundActivated(args);
    await new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("test").ShowAsync();
    //DoBackgroundWork(args.TaskInstance);
}
```